# How to configure server for Ruby on Rails 3 for many users where each user has his own set of gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

Could somebody help me, please? I would use Passenger + nginx to run Rails but how to do that if each user wants to have his own set of gems?

Answer (score 0):

Use RVM with each user has his own gem directory